# clearInterval created in useEffect hook from outside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, setinterval

I have this code, i'd like to clearInterval from outside this component (let's assume that I render a button with onClick method that calls clearInterval function).
I tried to pass interval value as a ref, but as soon as state updates this value changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (intervalRef.current as ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined) = setInterval(() => {
      fetch().then((items) => {
        items.forEach((item, id) => {
         // set state based on the values
        });
      });
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [state]);
```

I'm also getting eslint warning for `return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current)`, so I assume that it won't clear properly inside this method as well.

"The ref value 'intervalRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'intervalRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function."

What is the correct approach of such issues in React?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "I tried to pass interval value as a ref, but as soon as state updates this value changes."? This is how refs work and how you've coded the effect, each time the `state` dependency changes the effect runs again and will update the ref's value.

Comment: so, right now I'm creating ref like this `const intervalRef = useRef();` and assign interval value to it as seen above. I'd like to preserve the value of this ref/interval, so it can be cleared from outside this component and instead every time I fetch data and update the state this value changes. I assume that I'm creating lots of intervals which I can't clear

Comment: That is what a ref does though... you can reference the current value at any moment from anywhere within the function component scope.

Comment: so the problem is not with the ref, but with the interval itself, right? Am I creating many intervals right now?

Comment: You are creating one active interval per `state` update.

Comment: @DrewReese that's not how it supposed to be handled, right? Is there a way to create an interval once (like passing ref to useEffect array or something like this)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to only instantiate 1 interval timer when the component mounts, and clear it either when the component unmounts or in a button click's callback? If so, then remove `state` from the `useEffect`'s dependency array.

Comment: Right, but then again, my state won't update. I tried to prepare test env, but it seems to work there. To sum up, is it okay to create new interval on every re-render? With the useEffect cleanup function, it will be cleared anyway, is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241746/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-viciousp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The ref value 'intervalRef.current' will likely have changed by the
> time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node
> rendered by React, copy 'intervalRef.current' to a variable inside the
> effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function."

This is saying to save a reference to the ref value in the `useEffect` hook's callback closure, to be used in the cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  (intervalRef.current as ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined) = setInterval(() => {
    fetch().then((items) => {
      items.forEach((item, id) => {
       // set state based on the values
      });
    });
  }, 5000);

  const timerId = intervalRef.current;

  return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [state]);
```

If you need to, or want to, clear the interval from anywhere else in the component scope, just clear the interval as you would normally with the current ref value:

```
clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
```

Comment: and what if I want to pass this value to another component? So, I can clear this interval from outside useEffect method?

Comment: Regarding edits that you made to your answer - I tried that and it doesn't really work. Data is still being fetched

Comment: @viciousP Are you referring to in-flight network requests needing to also be cancelled if the interval is cleared? That is an entirely different question to "I need to clear an interval". Is that something you also need help with?

Comment: No, I'm getting network requests as if interval wouldn't be cleared at all. I tried to log  passed ref value and it is showing different values every 5 seconds which seems that the interval is being created every time state updates. My impression is that it's wrong and that's why I can't really clear it.

Comment: @viciousP I see. Sounds like you either aren't capturing the interval's timer id correctly or you might be mutating the ref value elsewhere. Could you try making a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live? You can mock the fetch function.

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      fetch().then((items) => {
        items.forEach((item, id) => {
         // set state based on the values
        });
      });
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [state]);
```

You dont need to make it a ref, if all you want is to clean the interval on unmount. Just assign it to a variable and pass it to your cleanup function.

Note: i see you are planning on doing a state update in promise. you might run into issue where component is unmounted and then the promise callback is triggered which tries to update state. so maybe put a isMounted check

Comment: that makes sense, but then again, how do you clear this interval from outside the component? I have a button and I'd like to pass this interval value to the button as a props